# Get x and y coords of touch input (Android studio, Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get the x and y coords of the touch input. I am trying to do this using:

```
package com.example.benjamin.labb3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Random;

import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

    public class Main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    DrawView drawView;
    String inputAction = "";
    Point touch;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);
        drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        drawView.resume();
    }

    @Override public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        drawView.pause();
    }

    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        touch.x = (int)event.getX();
        touch.y= (int)event.getY();
        return true;
    }

    public class  DrawView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        Thread gameloop = null;
        SurfaceHolder surface;
        volatile boolean running = false;
        AssetManager assets = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
        Bitmap incect[];
        int frame = 0;

        public DrawView(Context context){
            super(context);
            surface = getHolder();
            assets = context.getAssets();
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            incect = new Bitmap[2];

            try {
                for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++){
                    String fileName = "incect"+Integer.toString(n+1)+".png";
                    InputStream istream = assets.open(fileName);
                    incect[n] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream,null,options);
                    istream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void resume() {
            running = true;
            gameloop = new Thread(this);
            gameloop.start();
        }

        public void pause() {
            running = false;
            boolean retry = true;
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    gameloop.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }

        @Override public void run(){

            Point size = new Point();
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            display.getSize(size);
            Random wR = new Random();
            Random hR = new Random();
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;
            int randomW = wR.nextInt(width-20)+20;
            int randomH = hR.nextInt(height-20)+20;

            while (running){

                if(!surface.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;

                Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(85,107,47));
                canvas.drawBitmap(incect[frame],randomW-10,randomH-10,null);
                surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                frame ++;
                if (frame > 1){
                    frame = 0;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try to run the application on my phone (and touch the screen) i get sent back to the previous activity. As of now i cant use the log in android studio so i understand if it is a difficult question to answer.

Comment: Hi, do you have anymore code? Can you post the other activity?

Comment: Don't understand why you can't use Log. You could also consider use `Toast.makeText(this, touch.x + " " + touch.y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in your onTouch function.

Comment: There is something wrong with my emulator, it wont start. I only get to the android splash screen.. I can post the whole script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Point` touch is NULL all the time isn't it ?
Probably you forgot to initialize it :

```
touch = new Point();
```

without this line,  the variable `touch` is null all the time, so when onTouch() is called, Logcat will say :
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.graphics.Point.x' on a null object reference

So add the above line in `onCreate()` or somewhere it can be initialized before `onTouch()` is called,
Hope this helps.